# Touch events are not triggered on video tags on safari for iPhone

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, dom, safari

I want to prevent the scrolling on a safari web page for iphone by binding the preventDefault method on the document element of the DOM, and it works on every elements but the video tag.

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){e.preventdefault();}, false);
```

I've tried attaching the event to the video tags, but it seems as if nothing is attached or the events are simply not triggered.

Comment: Has anyone tried this on iOS4?

Comment: @Jeff I tried on iOS4 and the bug is still there.

Answer (score 1):

In my test, when ommiting the "controls" attribute of the video you can get the events....

By example....

```
<video src="http://192.168.1.53/videoTester/Cuatro.mp4" id="player" width="100%" height="100%" x-webkit-airplay="allow" ></video>
```

Then put a div in top... and it works for me....