# Preventing touchmove events in a <video> element in Mobile Safari

Tags: iphone, webkit, mobile-safari, html5-video

I am writing a home-screen web app with a video element in Mobile Safari. For usability reasons, I would prefer that swiping on the screen does not make the page scroll. I can successfully prevent swipes from scrolling using the following code. However, if a user swipes on the video element, the page scrolls.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no;"/> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<title>no scroll</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    },false);
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>anything but the video will be stationary when swiped.</p>
<video preload="auto" webkit-playsinline id="video" controls height="100" width="100">
    <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried adding code to prevent the video element from swallowing those events (inserted into the window.onload function):

```
var videoEl = document.getElementById('video');
videoEl.addEventListener('touchmove',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
},false);
videoEl.addEventListener('touchstart',function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Is there a workaround for this? Am I addressing the problem the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend putting a shim on top, that is, a blank div with a higher z-index to catch the touch events. I don't have a chance to test now, but should be pretty easy to try out.

Comment: Ah, right. That makes me think this question has been answered a million times before. I will give it a shot.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion with no avail. I am beginning to think what I am trying to do isn't possible. Here's a related question on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2874353/touch-events-are-not-triggered-on-video-tags-on-safari-for-iphone

Comment: I managed to have an overlayed shim capture events as long as the video element doesn't have the "controls" attribute enabled. Hope that helps.